# Is it 'Have ever read' or 'ever have read?'

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, sentence-choice

Take the following two sentence structures as examples:

1. This is the best book I *have ever read.*
2. This is the best book I *ever have read.*

Although the first one is more frequently used, I want to know if there is anything grammatically wrong if we use the second.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is grammatically correct and it is not just the frequency of its usage

as I remember:

the adverbs of frequency come before the main verb like : read, eat, sit, drive and etc...
and the main verb in this sentence is ?

**Read**

so I have ever read is the best choice

and I haven't seen anything like the second sentence even in slang speaking

maybe you could provide some of it if **you have ever seen** something like it

Comment: See example 2 in the picture: https://drive.google.com/file/d/17Hy8Jh7gpc-WEUcWtAogTarBtNRLDgTI/view?usp=sharing

Comment: _All_ those sentences have something wrong with them! (_Have gone_ would be OK in No. 4, but _taxis_ is spelt wrong.) There is an old-fashioned construction "...I ever did see" which is sometimes used (see the first answer to https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30686/did-see-and-saw), but it isn't used with other verbs.